# How to SOAP over a proxy server I own(configuration)?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, rewrite, web-services, soap

I have a server called **`http://SERVER-A.com`** which sends a **`SOAP`** request to a third-party address. Also I have another server called **`http://Server-B.com`** which I want to configure as a **proxy server**. I want to send my `SOAP` requests from **`A`** to the third-party server through server **`B`** (proxy my request). also I want to proxy SOAP requests only if the request **wants to be proxied**(from A to third party / not a direct request to **`B`**). I have configured my server **`B`** `htaccess` file as follows :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_FORWARDED} .
RewriteRule ^ - [P]

ProxyPassReverse / %{HTTP_FORWARDED}
```

Is my configuration correct?
What should I do beside this?

I know that I should configure my proxy host and port in `SOAP` request.(`php` client)
I have access only to `.htaccess` file.

I just want server **`B`** to act as a middleware.(like its **`B`** that is sending the `SOAP` request)

Thanks for your help.